# Como criar CheckBox via programação

Tags: java, android, checkbox

Como criar vários `Checkbox's` via programação?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ListView`. `ListView` organiza os itens em vertical e possui um adaptador que cria um `View` necessário para cada item da lista.

Coloque o ListView onde deseja no layout. Por exemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lista_presenca"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Agora na classe da atividade crie uma classe interna que estende `ArrayAdapter<Aluno>`. `Aluno` é a classe do aluno com suas informações. A extensão ficará parecida com a classe a seguir:

```
private class AlunoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Aluno> {

    public AlunoAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Aluno aluno = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = new CheckBox(getContext());
        }

        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView;

        checkBox.setText(aluno.getNome());
        checkBox.setChecked(false);

        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // salva no banco de dados se o aluno está presente ou não
            }
        });

        return checkBox;
    }
}
```

E o `onCreate(Bundle)`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView listaPresenca = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista_presenca);

    Aluno[] alunos = BancoDeDados.obterAlunos();

    AlunoAdapter adapter = new AlunoAdapter();
    adapter.addAll(alunos);

    listaPresenca.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Cada vez que eu for criar um checkBox terei que chamar a classe Aluno(Que já criei) e depois chamar o método getview é isso ?

Comment: Não. A `ListView` chama o `getView` quando precisar.

Comment: funcionou, só estou perdido nesse BancodeDados.obterAlunos();

Comment: `BancodeDados.obterAlunos();` é usado para obter os alunos a aparecerem na lista. Pode ser de outro lugar, eu usei um banco de dados como exemplo. Por onde você consegue a lista de alunos?

Answer (score 4):

Para criar `CheckBox` programaticamente basta você fazer desta forma:

```
CheckBox meuCheckbox = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
meuCheckbox.setText("Programaticamente criado");
```

Para verificar se está ativado ou desativado você pode usar o método `setOnCheckedChangeListener()`:

```
meuCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                 //checkbox habilitado
            } else {
                 //checkbox desabilitado
            }                  
        }
});
```

Para você adicionar ele no seu `ListView`, por exemplo, inserir um id e acrescentar o `CheckBox` utilizando o método `addView()`. Veja abaixo:

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="math_parent"
    android:layout_height="math_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/listview">

</LinearLayout>
```

**Classe**

```
ListView list = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.listview);
list.addView(meuCheckbox);
```

´
Para mais detalhes sobre `CheckBox`, veja [na documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox.html).